# Does Planck mass formula demonstrate a quantum theory of gravity?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity, physical-constants

Planck mass is equal to the square root of h-bar times G, divided by c. Replace G in the gravitational equation with planck mass, h-bar and c and then you result in a quantized equation for gravity. Does this not prove a quantum gravity theory?

Answer (score 3):

No. The fact that $\sqrt{c\hbar/G}$ is a mass just tells us roughly on what scale we'd likely expect quantum effects to matter. It took a lot more to quantize electromagnetism than just noticing $\sqrt{4\pi\varepsilon_0c\hbar}$ is a charge. In fact, that charge is almost $12$ times larger than that of an electron.

Comment: But if you plug that into the gravitational equation, it shows that an increase in mass will incrementally increase acceleration at the ratio of the h-bar times c divided by the planck mass. Isn't this what it means to have a quantized form of gravity?

Comment: @Shedbot Even before quantization, there's a lot more to gravity than $a=m/r^2$. Quantizing it means understanding how infinitely many Feynman diagrams combine to give a finite answer (ditto for electromagnetism, but we've done that).

Comment: @Shedbot No. In the equation you are referring to, you are allowed to change the mass continuously... so why would you think that the corresponding acceleration changes in quantised steps? But anyway, as J.G. pointed out, there is A LOT more to Quantum Gravity.

Comment: thanks JG that's essentially what I was asking. What is the electromagnetism quantized equation?

@koschi, I was under the impression that E = hv for example was a demonstration of the quantization of energy... if not, what is actually an equation that shows a quantized formula?

Comment: @Shedbot The goal is not discretization; it's renormalization. There's lots of material on this at various levels - I'm not sure what level is most appropriate (although [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555) introduction shows why gravity is harder) - but no one equation captures it all. It takes a whole mathematical theory of renormalization to understand this issue.